# Responsive design only working for some elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, margin

I started learning web development ≈ 3 weeks ago, so I'm relatively content where my first project went. The only issues are lying with the responsiveness of the design as there's a lot of disconnect there. I defaulted different div styles to 867px width since that's when a side navigation bar appears, and my goal was to iterate above and below that width.

This is how my website design looks like at the default 867px width

[image]

and it looks as intended more or less. I'm planning on adding a background video on the body div to add to the immersive interaction so I'm excited for that!

I made a ton of CSS designing to the div containers. The header responsiveness actually works as how I -- more or less -- intended, and believe me I was shocked I did not think that would work! The body text is also responding accordingly, where text is always centered relative to it's own div when the sidenav is active and not.

That sensation was rather short-lived, as I realized the rest of the responsiveness is acting clunky. The sidenav div is the biggest concern. I attempted to follow the same parameters as the header CSS, but it's not responding to the height as the frame increases in width, it just kinda stays stagnant. As a result, because the header increases in both width and length until 1310px, the sidenav is breaching into the header.

[image]

I understand why that's happening, I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong and/or what I'm not doing.

My project is a website/film portfolio, so I have a ton of photos ready to show. I intended to have it follow the same responsive formula. Unfortunately when the width is below 867px, the margin-left padding intended for the sidenav doesn't disappear and there's a gap on the left hand-side

[image]

of all my galleries. I'm actually not sure why this is the case, as the margin-left padding worked for the text I made in my body div's, and made a media screen code removing that padding (this worked).

This same technique is not working for the photos, which is strange because it's all falling under the same container. Of course, the top-padding isn't working either and the photos are leaking into the header, but I assume this is a easy fix when I figure out the sidenav issue (or vice versa).

Again, I'm relatively new, and I am very shocked I made it this far this fast. I'm just trying to figure out flexbox, or other responsive techniques that can cater to my individual case to optimize the flexibility of mobile-desktop intended audiences. I'm also a bit iffy about the coordinates I made, but I just might scrap all that or figure out another click solution for the sidenav.

The code for everything is below and added comments for everything not working:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: 0;
}


/* 1st div container - header */

.header {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #000000;
}


/* 2nd div container - sidebar */

.sidebar {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Inital position for sidebar */

#sidetoggle {
  padding-top: 0.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Inital position for launch */

.launch {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* Inital position for banner -- the navigation appearing on header when sidebar leaves below 867px*/

.banner {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 7.7rem;
  padding-left: 9rem;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.imagery {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
}


/* Adjust responsiveness for all pages */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header img {
    height: 135px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 867px) {
  .banner {
    display: none;
  }
  .sidemenu {
    width: 175px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 867px) {
  .sidemenu {
    display: none;
  }
  .body p,
  .body-2ndindex p,
  .body-3rdindex p {
    font-size: 5.5vmin;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  /* Not functioning */
  .body-2ndindex img,
  .body-3rdindex img {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1310px) {
  .header img {
    width: 99.9%;
  }
  /* Not functioning */
  .sidemenu img {
    height: 99.9%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1310px) {
  .header img {
    width: 1310px;
  }
  /* Not functioning */
  .sidemenu img {
    height: 200px;
  }
}


/* 3rd div container - body */

.body-landingindex {
  font-size: 54px;
  font-family: 'Limelight', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-left: 175px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  color: rgb(145, 145, 145);
}


/* Div containers for subsequent home pages in different HTML files - sidenav & header stay the same and are recycled in those HTML pages */

.body-2ndindex,
.body-3rdindex {
  font-size: 38px;
  margin-top: 160px;
  margin-left: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: 'Limelight', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <img src="heading.png" id="heading">
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <img src="photos.png" class="sidemenu" id="sidetoggle">
    <img name="sidemenu" src="sidemenumain.png" class="sidemenu" id="maintoggle" usemap="#m_sidemenu" alt="" />
    <map name="m_sidemenu" id="m_sidemenu">
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,196,24" href="example0.html" target="mainframe" alt="Musicans" />
            <a target = "_self" href = "examplepage1.html" target = "mainframe" alt = "example1"></a>
            <a target = "_self" href = "examplepage1.html" target = "mainframe" alt = "example2"><area shape = "rect" coords = "0,84,196,106"></a>
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,128,196,148" href="example1.html" target="mainframe" alt="stock photos" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,170,196,195" href="example2.html" target="mainframe" alt="celebrities" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,214,196,236" href="example3.html" target="mainframe" alt="services" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,258,196,279" href="example4.html" target="mainframe" alt="services" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="0,299,196,323" href="example5.html" target="mainframe" alt="services" />
            </map>
    <img src="extras.png" class="sidemenu" id="sidetoggle">
    <img name="sidemenu" src="sidemenuextra.png" class="sidemenu" id="maintoggle" usemap="#m_sidemenu" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="body">
    <p class=b ody-text> SAMPLE HEADER TEXT</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```